# JSON not outputting properly after using SerializeJSON

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to serialize the following into JSON and checking the output in two ways as shown below :

```
Line #13 : <cfset convertjson = SerializeJSON([ 
                                         { 
                                           "Id":"123",
                                           "Value":"1",
                                           "Desc":"Checking Description ",
                                           "Group":"1"

                                           }

                                        ])/>


Normal Output : <cfoutput>#convertjson#</cfoutput> 

<br/>

Dump Output: <cfdump var="#convertjson#">
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid CFML construct found on line 13 at column 98.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

:

The CFML compiler was processing:

    An expression beginning with SerializeJSON, on line 11, column 26.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    A cfset tag beginning on line 11, column 2.
```

But I verified the JSON I am using, it is a valid JSON. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ColdFusion 9 doesn't support using `:` when creating a struct. Try

```
<cfset convertjson = SerializeJSON([
  {
   Id = "123",
   value = "1",
   Desc = "Checking Description ",
   Group = "1"
  }
])/>
```

Comment: Cool, This works. Good that I asked about it here otherwise I would have been beating my head on this for long time. Thanks Matt.